# Action same as Func<TResult>?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

I came across a situation where i need some knowledge.

Below is the code:

```
// A function to match the delegate
public static int DoSomething()
{
   Console.WriteLine("i am called");
   return 1;
}

// Usage
Action action = () => DoSomething();
Func<int> func = () => DoSomething();
action();
func();
```

My understanding of `Action` used to be that it should match a delegate that accepts no parameter and returns nothing.

And for `Func<int>` that it should match a delegate that accepts no parameter and returns an `int`.

`DoSomething` method returns an integer, hence my question: `() => DoSomething()` is a delegate that returns an `int`. `Func` works as expected, but `Action` doesn't. Why? What am i failing to understand here?

The code compiles and runs properly, both output `i am called`. What i want to know is that why `Action action = () => DoSomething();` is not a compile time error?

Comment: *>>  but Action doesn't* — how exactly does it fail to work?

Comment: the codeline `Action<object> action = (x) => DoSomething(x);`, shouldn't it be a compile time error because `Action<object>` requires to match a delegate that doesn't return a value?

Comment: @singsuyash the C# compiler is smart enough to figure out that `(x) => DoSomething(x)` means different things depending on the context. When you use it to assign an `Action` variable, it generates an `Action`, not a `Func` and ignores the return result of `DoSomething(x)`.

Comment: You can call the `DoSomething` method and "ignore" the return value (e.g. `DoSomething(x)`) and you can use the return value (e.g. `var retVal = DoSomething(x)`) - Both will work and compile.

Comment: What is your question ? Your code is perfectly fine, it compiles and runs

Comment: What makes you think this won't compile? Perhaps you should have tried it first?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: `Action<object> action = (x) => DoSomething(x);` why this should generate exception ? Action accepts object parameter and 5 is `boxed` to object. Read something about `box` / `unbox`

Comment: @Fabjan: The OP wasn't asking about the `action(5)` call.

Comment: @Fabjan, i didn't say anything about generating exception. And the question is not about the parameter, its about the return type.

Comment: @singsuyash well, the return type for action is `void`, you can press `F12` to see how exactly `Action<T>` delegate is declared : `public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);`

Comment: @Fabjan, i updated my question again for you.

Comment: @JonSkeet, @ Alexander, @ Dmytro Shevchenko, @ Kyle, @ Todd Sprang, I am sorry i had to update the question for more clarity. Your answers have `Action<object>` that need to change now. Sorry again!

Comment: *Why* did you have to update the question? It was clear enough already - there was no need for that change. (I've updated my answer now, but in future I would urge you to only change the question like this when you *really* need to.)

Comment: @singsuyash`Action action = () => DoSomething();` here you call lambda that returns void and invokes DoSomething(); in it's body. Because this lambda returns void you do not have `Exception` here change it to `Action action = () => { return DoSomething(); }` and you'll have compile time error because now your Lamda returns int and not void.

Comment: @JonSkeet, i am sorry. My reasons to update it were that i could make the question more generic than to just let it use `object` and `int`. Also, it confused a few people about what i wanted. :(

Comment: "Method Group Conversion" was the missing concept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What i want to know is that why `Action action = () => DoSomething();` is not a compile time error?

It compiles because you've got a lambda expression that calls the method but ignores the result. You couldn't use a method group conversion, e.g.

```
// Compile-time failure
// error CS0407: 'int Test.DoSomething()' has the wrong return type
Action action = DoSomething;
```

(The same method group conversion for `Func<Action, int>` is fine.)

But instead, you're doing something more like this:

```
Action action = DoSomethingAndIgnoreResult;
...
private static void DoSomethingAndIgnoreResult()
{
    DoSomething(); // Hey, I'm ignoring the result. That's fine...
}
```

Comment: It's might worth noting that the error for the method group conversion is something like `Expected a method with 'void DoSomething(object)' signature`

Comment: @DaveZych: Done, with the actual error message I get.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet for the updated answer :) and yes ill be careful in future to not change it like this.

Answer (score 9):

`Action action = () => DoSomething();` is equivalent to 
`Action action = () => { DoSomething(); };`

`Func<int> func = () => DoSomething();` is equivalent to 
`Func<int> func = () => { return DoSomething(); };`

Answer (score 3):

The C# compiler is smart enough to figure out that `() => DoSomething()` means different things depending on the context. When you use it to assign an `Action` variable, it generates an `Action` (instead of `Func<int>`) that ignores the return result of `DoSomething()`.

Answer (score 1):

> `DoSomething` method returns an integer, hence my question: `(x) => DoSomething(x)` is a delegate that accepts an `object` and returns an `int`. `Func` works as expected, but `Action` doesn't. Why? What am i failing to understand here?

The flaw in your understanding is right here: `(x) => DoSomething(x)` doesn't have a type.  It isn't anything.  The compiler requires context to figure out what the type of this is.  By itself a lambda isn't anything in particular, this is why you can't use `var` with a lambda expression: the compiler doesn't know what type the lambda should be, so it can't deduce the type.

For example, `(x) => DoSomething(x)` could also be an expression tree:

```
Expression<Func<object, int>> e = (x) => DoSomething(x)
```

So you're telling the compiler how to interpret a lambda based on the type you're assigning it to.

Answer (score 0):

All your understandings are correct. It's your specific usage that may be causing confusion. Both Func and Action are just fine. Both calls are just fine. I think the case that may illuminate your issue is:

`var x = action(5); // NOT ok
var y = func(5); // ok`

Your sample code just ignores the return value, which is why it seems like they're the same. No different than

`void Foo1(int x) { return; }
void Foo2(int x) { return 1; }
Foo1(5);
Foo2(5);`